# Trying to Copy from one Sheet to the first empty cell on another column

Tags: excel, vba

I am basically merging two sheets together. It works for the first sheet but then when doing it for the second sheetit fails at the below line on the 'Copying columns from "Open Task" sheet section.

`OT2sourceCol.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=.Cells(OT2firstEmptyRow, i) 'Copy the entire column to the "Combined Tasks and Incidents" sheet starting from the first empty row in the target column`

It gives me an error:

`Run-time error '1004' You can't paste this here because the Copy area and paste area aren't the same size. Select just one cell in the paste area or an area that's the same size, and try pasting again.`

Maybe I am just overthinking this.
Below is the whole code:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open IM")
.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
.Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).TextToColumns Destination:=.Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Next i
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim lastCol As Long
lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To lastRow
For j = 1 To lastCol
If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, j)) Then
.Cells(i, j).Value = "ThisCellEmpty"
End If
Next j
Next i
End With
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open Task")
    .Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
    For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).TextToColumns Destination:=.Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Next i
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        For j = 1 To lastCol
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, j)) Then
            .Cells(i, j).Value = "ThisCellEmpty"
End If
Next j
Next i
End With

'Creating new sheet "Combined Tasks and Incidents"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Combined Tasks and Incidents"

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Tasks and Incidents")
.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Number"
.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Subject"
.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Assignment group"
.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Assigned to"
.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Count Days"
.Cells(1, 6).Value = "Company"
.Cells(1, 7).Value = "Reopen count"
.Cells(1, 8).Value = "Controllable/Non-Controllable"
.Cells(1, 9).Value = "Created by"
.Cells(1, 10).Value = "Channel"
.Cells(1, 11).Value = "Priority"
.Cells(1, 12).Value = "Resolved"
.Cells(1, 13).Value = "Closed"
.Cells(1, 14).Value = "Reassignment count"
.Cells(1, 15).Value = "Caller"
.Cells(1, 16).Value = "State"
.Cells(1, 17).Value = "On hold reason"
.Cells(1, 18).Value = "Knowledge"
.Cells(1, 19).Value = "Category"
.Cells(1, 20).Value = "Subcategory"
.Cells(1, 21).Value = "Created"
.Cells(1, 22).Value = "Day"
.Cells(1, 23).Value = "Closed"
.Cells(1, 24).Value = "Contact Type"
End With

'Copying columns from "Open IM" sheet
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Tasks and Incidents")
        Dim targetLastCol As Long
        targetLastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To targetLastCol
            Dim targetCol As String
            targetCol = .Cells(1, i).Value 'The name of the column in the "Combined Tasks and Incidents" sheet
            Dim sourceCol As Range
            Set sourceCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open IM").Range("A:Z").Find(targetCol, LookIn:=xlValues) 'Find the column in the "Open IM" sheet with the same name
            If Not sourceCol Is Nothing Then
                sourceCol.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=.Cells(1, i) 'Copy the entire column to the "Combined Tasks and Incidents" sheet
            End If
        Next i
    End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Tasks and Incidents")
.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
.Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).TextToColumns Destination:=.Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Next i
Dim CTIlastRow As Long
CTIlastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim CTIlastCol As Long
CTIlastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To CTIlastRow
For j = 1 To CTIlastCol
If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, j)) Then
.Cells(i, j).Value = "ThisCellEmpty"
End If
Next j
Next i
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Tasks and Incidents")
.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Short Description"
End With

'Copying columns from "Open Task" sheet
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Tasks and Incidents")
    Dim OT2targetLastCol As Long
    OT2targetLastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To OT2targetLastCol
        Dim OT2targetCol As String
        OT2targetCol = .Cells(1, i).Value 'The name of the column in the "Combined Tasks and Incidents" sheet
        Dim OT2sourceCol As Range
        Set OT2sourceCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open Task").Range("A:Z").Find(OT2targetCol, LookIn:=xlValues) 'Find the column in the "Open Task" sheet with the same name
        If Not OT2sourceCol Is Nothing Then
            Dim OT2firstEmptyRow As Long
            OT2firstEmptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            OT2sourceCol.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=.Cells(OT2firstEmptyRow, i) 'Copy the entire column to the "Combined Tasks and Incidents" sheet starting from the first empty row in the target column
        End If
    Next i
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: You can't copy an entire column (which - don't forget includes the blank cells) - so that's all 1,048,576 cells into anywhere other than a cell on the first row. Any lower than that is not going to fit. You need to reduce the size of the range being copied - for example, to the last used cell.

Comment: You are so right! I need to go back and select from the last active cell and up and then copy and paste. I'll do that after I take a nap but thank you! Let's see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix which selects the last cell with data and up and the copies and apstes rather than the entire column. This does not delete the header but that's for another question/brain storming.

````
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Tasks and Incidents")
Dim OT2targetLastCol As Long
OT2targetLastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To OT2targetLastCol
Dim OT2targetCol As String
OT2targetCol = .Cells(1, i).Value 'The name of the column in the "Combined Tasks and Incidents" sheet
Dim OT2sourceCol As Range
Set OT2sourceCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open Task").Range("A:Z").Find(OT2targetCol, LookIn:=xlValues) 'Find the column in the "Open Task" sheet with the same name
If Not OT2sourceCol Is Nothing Then
Dim OT2lastRow As Long
OT2lastRow = OT2sourceCol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Dim OT2firstEmptyRow As Long
OT2firstEmptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1
OT2sourceCol.Resize(OT2lastRow, 1).Copy Destination:=.Cells(OT2firstEmptyRow, i) 'Copy the entire column to the "Combined Tasks and Incidents" sheet starting from the first empty row in the target column
End If
Next i
End With```
````